# How to get app title/link directed over to a website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

You know the publishing apps on Facebook: "Published via ***_*__*_***".

I've see a few times where when you click on the app name, it goes directly to the provider's website?  (For example, if I clicked on it, it would direct to www.mywebsite.com)

For the life of me, I can't figure out how they make that work.  Can't find a setting in the developer app.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of application that does it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just done via a facebook page or application. If you create the facebook application, and post content via the application, it will automatically show the "Published via ..." at the bottom.

What it does is redirect you to the application page (so FB can track the number of clicks) then it will auto redirect to the website url page specified in the application settings.

Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.mad4flash.com/2011/09/how-to-update-facebook-status-via-application/)